# Which way is efficient: build a list and then convert it to numpy array or from the begining use numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, pytorch

- Operating System: Windows, 64
- Python version: 3.7.11
- PyTorch version: 1.10.0 - cpu only
- IDE: Jupyter Notebook (with conda env)

I have a class with `x_indices` and `x_tokens` properties.

The class is not necessary, but if you think it helps you can download it [here](https://icedrive.net/0/0fccRIBCFM).

These two properties are empty lists at first and get elements (list elements) over time.

`x_indices` get list of numbers

`x_tokens` get list of strings

```
# x_tokens looks something like:
[["first", "second"], 
 ["third", "forth"], 
 ..., 
 ["n-1th", "nth"]
]
```

At the end, each of two lists have 9019 rows and 18427 columns.

I want to use `x_tokens` as input to a convolutional neural network in PyTorch.

Question:

Given that `x_tokens` and `x_indices` will have large shape, which below ways in defining them is more efficient and why?

- first, define it as **list** and then convert it to **nparray** and then convert it to **PyTorch tensor** or
- first, define it as **nparray** and then convert it to **PyTorch tensor** or
- from the first, define it as **PyTorch tensor** tensor

Comment: Did you try the different approaches yourself? What kind of results did you get?

Comment: Take a look at the `timeit` module

Comment: Not yet. I just tried lists and it takes times. I have several .csv files and if each one takes this time and RAM for converting txt to list of words because of just using inefficient data structure, it will take a lot of time and sometimes it shows RAM exceed error just for processing one .csv file. @np8

Comment: How large is your list? Which dimension of the elements?

Comment: 9019 rows, and the number of columns is variable for example 1000 or more. @Jaja